# RxJava. Observable.OnSubscribe cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm trying to write my first code in RxJava but i've encountered with some error of library import i suppose.

```
package second.pack;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable <String> observable = Observable.create(
// the line below marked as it has an error in Eclipse
/* 7 line */    new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void call (Subscriber <String> sub){
                      sub.onNext("New Datas");
                      sub.onComplete(); 
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

The Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Observable.OnSubscribe cannot be resolved to a type
    at second.pack.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

[image]

Please, can anybody help me with this error?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you possibly meant `ObservableOnSubscribe<String>` instead of `Observable.OnSubscribe<String>`?

Comment: As i know Observable.OnSubscribe<T> is a nested interface of Observable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up constructs between 1.x and 2.x. Are you working with an older tutorial? Try this instead:

```java
import io.reactivex.*;

public class ObservableOnSubscribeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(
                new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> sub){
                        sub.onNext("New Datas");
                        sub.onComplete(); 
                    }
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the correct version of RxJava on your classpath? It looks like you're attemping to use RxJava 1.x (`io.reactivex.Observable`) but `Observable.OnSubscribe` was added in RxJava 2.x (`rx.Observable`)

Comment: In any case can you tell me please what exactly do i have to import to compile that code?

Comment: You have it wrong. `rx.Observable.OnSubscribe` was an interface on RxJava 1.x. `io.reactivex.Observable` was introduced in RxJava 2.x by splitting the v1 `rx.Observable` into backpressure supporting (`Flowable`) and non-supporting variants.

Comment: Oops, you're right, i had it exactly backward. I mixed up which tab had which javadoc :)